# check first time login only

Tags: redirect, login

i want to display welcome message or redirect the user to my custom template when the user login for the first time only. After the user can visit the regular page of the site.

Answer (score 15):

Whenever a new user is created, this function will add a custom field with value 1.

```
function function_new_user($user_id) { 
   add_user_meta( $user_id, '_new_user', '1' );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'function_new_user');
```

The next function will check if it's the first login and redirect the user.

```
function function_check_login_redirect($user_login, $user) {
   $logincontrol = get_user_meta($user->ID, '_new_user', 'TRUE');
   if ( $logincontrol ) {
      //set the user to old
      update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_new_user', '0' );

      //Do the redirects or whatever you need to do for the first login
      wp_redirect( 'http://www.example.com', 302 ); exit;
   }
}
add_action('wp_login', 'function_check_login_redirect', 10, 2);
```

Tip: The function_check_login_redirect knows the user. You can even offer the user a custom info or call to action.